# Google maps API autocomplete drop down style, :focus does not work when navigating with arrows

Tags: css, google-maps

Basically I want to change the style of drop down menu of autocomplete.
There is a main div of `pac-container` and divs inside (`pac-items`).

I have the following css code:

```
.pac-tem:hover, .pac-tem:focus {
    background-color: black;
}
```

For hover it works just fine. But When I navigate with arrows it uses default style

Can anyone help?

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem, I resolved using the class in css

```
.pac-selected {
    background-color: black; 
}
```